# Constant BSODs on my windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod

I am having constant BSODs with no matter what I do; with different error codes. 
I am using `windows 7 32bit CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E7200` 
On BlueScreenView, I don't know if its important but in every .dmp there is ntoskrnl.exe file
Usual bugcheck codes are: `0xfe    0xa     0xd1     0x124`

Here are last 5 [minidump](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=8cdfca356089516f&id=8CDFCA356089516F!140) files:

Comment: Your screenshots didn't post. Upload them someplace and post a link. You could be having hardware problems...have you investigated with diagnostic tools? What about System Restore?

Answer (score 2):

You use a preRelease version of Windows 7 (Build 7127 : `7127.0.x86fre.winmain.090507-1820`). Update to the final version of Windows 7, [install the Sp1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1) and now look if you still get the issue.